# List of List in Data Frame

Tags: linux, unix, r, dataframe

I have a data that is generated like this:

```
> dat1 <- data.frame(V1 = rep(1, 5), V2 = sample(c(40:45), 5))
> dat2 <- data.frame(V1 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE), V2 = sample(c(40:45), 5, replace = TRUE))
```

What I want to do is to obtain a data frame that contain list of list.

```
> hiv
$hiv.dat1
$hiv.dat1$V1[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

$hiv.dat1$V2[[1]]
[1] 41 42 43 40 44


$hiv.dat2
$hiv.dat2$V1[[1]]
[1] 0 1 1 0 0

$hiv.dat2$V2[[1]]
[1] 42 43 40 44 43
```

But why this line of command failed to create that?

```
> hiv <- list(hiv.dat1 = as.list(dat1), hiv.dat2 = as.list(dat2))
```

Especially it gives  "$hiv.dat1$V1" instead of "$hiv.dat1$V1[[1]]".

How can we correct that?
I need this particular data structure required for a specific package (ROCR).

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you want - `str(hiv)` shows that your command created a list which contains two sub-lists. All the following work to access the first column of the first sublist: `hiv$hiv.dat1$V1` or `hiv$hiv.dat1[[1]]` or `hiv[[1]][[1]]` or even `hiv[[1]]$V1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want each element of the data frame to become its own list (of length one); your code instead makes each data frame into a list containing the elements of the data frame.  You need to apply the `list` function to each element individually with `lapply`.

```
hiv <- list(hiv.dat1 = lapply(dat1, list), hiv.dat2 = lapply(dat2, list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Only `list` type can be

- nested (ie recurse)
- contain objects of different type *and* length

So in short no nesting of data frames, but you can pile different data frames inside a list.

(And please do not crosspost here and on r-help.)